# Getting java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/Rectangle error

Tags: selenium

I am trying to run a piece of selenium code in my local instance and running into this error. Please help me figure out this issue as I couldn't find anything over any of the blogs

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/Rectangle

    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetPublicMethods(Class.java:2902)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethods(Class.java:1615)
    at sun.misc.ProxyGenerator.generateClassFile(ProxyGenerator.java:451)
    at sun.misc.ProxyGenerator.generateProxyClass(ProxyGenerator.java:339)
    at java.lang.reflect.Proxy$ProxyClassFactory.apply(Proxy.java:639)
    at java.lang.reflect.Proxy$ProxyClassFactory.apply(Proxy.java:557)
    at java.lang.reflect.WeakCache$Factory.get(WeakCache.java:230)
    at java.lang.reflect.WeakCache.get(WeakCache.java:127)
    at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.getProxyClass0(Proxy.java:419)
    at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.newProxyInstance(Proxy.java:719)
    at
```

Comment: can you provide your code and pom.xml file?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing this dependency in pom.xml:

The following code worked for me

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
<artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
<version>2.53.1</version>
</dependency>
```